# In Oracle database, how do I remove the expiration date for my HR user?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00931

I'm following the dir. here on this link :

[How do I turn off Oracle password expiration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095871/how-do-i-turn-off-oracle-password-expiration)

But it's not letting my remove the expiry date for my HR user :

Here is what I tried (and a screenshot of ouput):

```
SELECT profile from DBA_USERS where username = 'HR';
```

[image]

And then I run :

```
ALTER profile 'HR' limit password_life_time UNLIMITED;
```

It gives me back :

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00931: missing identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT password_life_time UNLIMITED;
```

[image]